# How to rename "Options" menu in Symbian app?

Tags: c++, localization, symbian

My Qt application for Symbian supports several languages and I've managed to translate everything, but the only thing remains unchanged is menu bar, that is named "Options", even when I change phone locale, the name for menu bar remains the same.

Additionally, when I open menu, softkeys have names "Select" and "Cancel", although these names change when I change phone locale.

So, my question is - is there a way to rename menu bar, and change softkeys when menu is opened without changing phone locale?

EDIT: Alternatively, Symbian-native code, that allows to rename left soft key, would be fine.

Comment: How do the other (non Qt) applications behave when you change phone's language? 
I tested with some Nokia phones and when changing language then after reboot Options was translated correctly (like all the other menus).

Comment: @Riho "Options" text doesn't change on my test phones (E66 and X6) on phone locale change. Which phones have you tested on? What is Qt version you are using? I'm on 4.7.3.

Comment: I used E6. So even with built-in applications (Clock, Contacts, etc.) the Options text is shown in english?

Comment: No, built-in apps are fine, the problem is with Qt apps.

Comment: Ahh,ok. In my Qt apps I used fullscreen mode, so I didn't have any softkeys visible. Might be that Qt overrides them and forgot to support translation

Answer (score 1):

Normally the Options and Cancel names match the phone's locale. If you want to translate them into another language, here's how to change the right softkey at runtime in native Symbian:

```
// Change the Exit softkey to Hide
HBufC* hideText(CCoeEnv::Static()->AllocReadResourceLC(R_MYAPP_HIDE));
TInt pos(Cba()->PositionById(EAknSoftkeyExit));
Cba()->RemoveCommandFromStack(pos, EAknSoftkeyExit);
Cba()->SetCommandL(pos, EPodOClockCmdHide, *hideText);
CleanupStack::PopAndDestroy(hideText);
```

Try `EAknSoftkeyOptions` to change the left softkey.

Comment: I'm not very good at native Symbian coding, can you please help me? I don't know which headers I need to include, and which libraries to link.

Comment: Search [Nokia Developer](https://www.developer.nokia.com/). The API library will tell you which headers and libraries are needed. Also check [this](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Change_softkeys_dynamically_(either_right_or_left_or_both)) which says you need eikbtgpc.h and eikcoctl.lib.